# openlayers: adding unique data to a feature and referencing it

Tags: controls, openlayers

How can I attach some unique data to a feature in openlayers and then reference it? I have seen lots of examples where data can be set before the map is loaded but none when the features are being set through a click control.

I have my control which draws the point but I want to add some data to it and then reference it later within the onclick popup. feature.somedata is just to show where I would want it to be referenced.

```
supp: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(featuresLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.Point) 

"<div style='font-size:.8em'>Feature: " + feature.id + "<br/> Some data:"+feature.somedata+"."+"<br/></div>",
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a attribute for this called feature.attributes. The data that is loaded is stored there. So you just have to put like:

```
feature.attributes = { "somedata" : "value", "unique_id": "x"};
```

Did it answered your question?

Comment: (+1) can be stored in `feature.attributes` or `feature.data`

Comment: My main problem had been setting data to the new features I was creating on click.  

I ended up with a temporaryFeature which was created when the page loaded. Its variables changed through other UI clicks.  

`temporaryFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(featuresLayer,new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0.0,0.0),{}); `  

`'R': new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(featuresLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.Point,{featureAdded: setFeatureData})`  

`temporaryFeature .attributes['uniqueid'] = 'value';`